# is there any way I can have two complex types in one element schema ? I'm using 1.0 V

Tags: xml, xsd, schema, xsd-validation, xsd-1.1

This is my schema file:

```
<xs:element name="elementname">
  <xs:complexType/>
</xs:element>
```

Currently, the file which validating:

```
<ElementDef name="elementname" visible="false">
  <elementname/>
</ElementDef>
```

But now I want this schema to accept this also the previous schema (i.e. I want some kind of choice that it accepts meta tag also if it has any)

```
<ElementDef name="elementname" visible="false">
  <Section>
    <Sequence>
      <SectionType name="meta">
    </Sequence>
  </Section>    
  <elementname/>
</ElementDef>
```

This is what I have tried, but doesn't work:

```
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xs:element name="Section" minOccurs="0">
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="Sequence" minOccurs="0">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
            <xs:attribute name="friendly" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
            <xs:attribute name="style" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
            <xs:attribute name="numbering" use="optional">
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
```

Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Comment: So is elementname exclusive of Section? e.g. they can't both be there?  If both can be there, is one or more of them optional?

Answer (score 0):

Your post is confusing in very many ways. For example, you say in the text that you are using 1.0, but you have tagged it 1.1.

An xs:choice normally offers more than one alternative - for some reason you've got two xs:choice elements, and each of them only offers one alternative.

I think you just want a sequence in which `Section` is optional:

```
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element name="Section" minOccurs="0">
       ...
     </xs:element>
     <xs:element name="elementName">
       ...
     </xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```